# jQuery: Select elements which doesn't have a child with different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, parent-child

I want to select all `div` elements which do not have direct child elements with class name neither `"class1"` nor `"class2"`. This means selector should select only those elements which are not parent of `"class1"` and `"class2"`

The following works if there is only one class for the child:

```
$('#wrapper .myDiv:not(:has(>.class1))');
```

I should exclude from list the elements that are parent of `"class2"` as well. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please add your HTML or create a JSfiddle

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lt5o1sgd/2/